# Manually Build a Login Flow for Facebook Canvas and non-Canvas

Tags: facebook, canvas

I want to manually build a login flow for Facebook Canvas and non-Canvas.

For Facebook Canvas, my Redirect_URI is:
https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/callback

For Facebook non-Canvas (plain web app), my Redirect_URI is: https://www.myapp.com/callback

How to detect in which situation I am, in order to redirect to the appropriate URL?

The [official doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow) is silent about this Canvas problem.

Comment: When your app is initially loaded into the canvas iframe, it gets a `signed_request` parameter POSTed to it. Decode it and look at what it contains.

Comment: Or you simply use the JS SDK for login purposes. That makes for a much nicer user experience on canvas (simple overlay dialog), and opens a popup when called in the normal web app.

Comment: @CBroe it is not so simple to use JS SDK, I already did everything manually, except this small detail, and my JS skills are very limited.